# How to make group of toggle buttons responsive

Tags: sapui5

The xml for toggle buttons:

```
<HBox id="toggleButtons1" fitContainer="false" class="fullWidthButtons" alignItems="Center">
            <items>
        <ToggleButton text="BUTTON1" enabled="true" pressed="true" press=".onPress1" class="firsttogglebutton" >
            <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
          </layoutData>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton text="BUTTON2" enabled="true" pressed="false" press=".onPress2">
            <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
          </layoutData>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton text="BUTTON3" enabled="true" pressed="false" press=".onPress3">
            <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
          </layoutData>
        </ToggleButton>
            </items>
    </HBox>
```

- Applied some CSS guess not required

I am checking for responsive,when viewed in small/medium devices it is perfect with all size of devices:

for ref:

[image]

But When I changed(Enlarged) text inside buttons, It is not responsive. What might be the reason? how to overcome this?

[image]

I tried my luck replacing HBox with FlexBox but it is same(May be I should include some more properties).

Controller.js:

```
sap.ui.define("myController", [
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
  "use strict";

  var toggleButtons1;

  return Controller.extend("myController", {
    onInit: function() {
      toggleButtons1 = this.byId("toggleButtons1").getItems();
    },

    onPressNext: function(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < toggleButtons1.length - 1; ++i) {
        if (toggleButtons1[i].getPressed()) {
          toggleButtons1[i].setPressed(false);
          toggleButtons1[i + 1].setPressed(true);
          break;
        }
      }
    },

    onPressPrevious: function() {
      for (var i = toggleButtons1.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        if (toggleButtons1[i].getPressed()) {
          toggleButtons1[i - 1].setPressed(true);
        }
      }
    },

    onPress: function(e) {
      var btn = e.getSource();
      if(!btn.getPressed()) {
        btn.setPressed(true);
        return;
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < toggleButtons1.length; ++i) {
        if (toggleButtons1[i] != btn) {
          toggleButtons1[i].setPressed(false);
        }
      }
    },

    onPress1: function(e) {
       this.onPress(e);
       alert("Do something here!");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `HBox` will not provide you the responsive layout. As per the 1st screenshot the button text length is different from the 2nd screenshot. If you want the responsive design then use responsive layouts like `Grid`

Comment: Yeah I have given different text length to observe the same,thought with smaller text it is responsive....May I know how to wrap them in a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view.xml**

```
<l:Grid id="gridToggleButtons" containerQuery="true" defaultSpan="XL2 L4 M4 S6">
  <ToggleButton text="BUTTON1EEE" enabled="true" pressed="true" press=".onPress1" class="firsttogglebutton" />
  <ToggleButton text="BUTTON2EEE" enabled="true" pressed="false" press=".onPress2" />
  <ToggleButton text="BUTTON3EEE" enabled="true" pressed="false" press=".onPress3" />
</l:Grid>
```

**controller.js**

```
var oGrid = this.byId("gridToggleButtons");
var oBtns = oGrid.getContent();
var oBUTTON1EEE = oBtns[0];
var oBUTTON2EEE = oBtns[1];
var oBUTTON3EEE = oBtns[2];
```

Note: `containerQuery` is used to get the size based on the Grid size not based on the device sizes(Large, Medium and Small).
`defaultSpan` is set based on your requirement. For more information regarding the Grid go through the [Grid API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Grid)

Comment: One question , is this a predefined class? `class="responsiveTBtn"`?

Comment: `class="responsiveTBtn"` is a custom class. You can remove it as well.

Comment: As we are not using  `HBox`, you cant use `toggleButtons1 = this.byId("toggleButtons1").getItems();`. There is  no  `getItems()` in the `Grid`. What you are trying to achieve with it?

Comment: I thought there is no `Id` included, so we are getting that error(no idea for this beginner), now how we do that in controller? ......

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can use the `getContent()`

Comment: I am stuck mate, I have included the controller for the previous one , may I know what I have to change here

Comment: I have added new ID `gridToggleButtons` to grid control. Now  you can access the grid layout instance in controller. Now you need to use the `getContent()` instead of `getItems()`

Comment: so instead of `toggleButtons1`  i need to use `oBtns ` rest all is same as previous right? .....